# Portability cast void**

Tags: c, pointers

I was reading http://c-faq.com/ptrs/genericpp.html when i found that ((void **)&ptr); "Not portably" , is that correct? because it seems to work...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void *wrapper_free(void **p){

     if(p){
       free(*p);
       *p=NULL;
     }

     return NULL;
}

int main() {

    int *ptr=malloc(sizeof(int));
    *ptr=20;

     printf("%d\n",ptr);

     wrapper_free((void **)&ptr); //Not portably?

     printf("%d",ptr);

     return 0;
}
```

Is ((void **)&ptr); portably?

Comment: Something which is definitely not portable, and is actually UB, is using mismatching `printf` specifier and argument. Your variable `ptr` is a pointer, it should be printed with the `"%p"` format specifier.

Comment: The page explains the issue and reasons it not being portable quite well. What part of it do you have problems with?

Comment: *because it seems to work* -- so does writing to an array outside it's bound on your machine. But it won't on my machine. That is precisely the meaning of portability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That only generic pointer that can be implicitly converted to any other pointer (to object) is `void*`. This pointer type has special rules in the standard. Those rules do not apply to `void**`, which is just a pointer type like any other.

This means you can't implicitly convert from `void**` to `int**` or vice versa, the conversion has to be done explicitly with a cast like in your code. If/how it works is implementation-defined. Meaning that what will happen depends on the system and compiler — it is indeed not portable (C11 6.3.2.3/7).

To make your snippet 100% portable, you will have to write:

```
void* vptr = ptr;
wrapper_free(&vptr);
ptr = vptr;
```

Answer (score 2):

Both the previous answers have covered why the code is not portable according to the standard. I just want to add an example of where it can go bad.

Suppose on a target `int*` doesn't have the same representation as `void*` and `void*` has a trap value.

Now, `ptr` is assigned a value from `void*` and the bit representation is automatically changed by the implicit cast.

Suppose the bit pattern stored in `ptr` corresponds exactly to the bit pattern for the trap representation for `void*`

Now you passed `&ptr` where `void**` is expected using an explicit cast.
When `wrapper_free` tries to dereference `p` (as a `void*`), it dereferences a trap value and nothing can be predicted about the program behavior beyond that point.

Instead if you create a temporary variable of type `void*` and assign to it the `int*`, the conversion back from `int*` to `void*` will occur and you are guaranteed to not hit the trap bit representation.

Hope, this helps understand the problem better.

Comment: This seems like wild speculations though. Are there actually any existing systems that have trap representation for `void*` but not for other pointer types?

Comment: @Lundin, no I am not aware. Infact I am not even aware of a system where the bit pattern for `int*` is different from that of `void*`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the code is not portable is that the second level of indirection (second asterisk) on top of `void*` cannot have any special treatment from the compiler. When you convert a pointer of any type to/from `void*`, the compiler knows to insert conversions both ways, so the construct is guaranteed to work. When you add a second asterisk, the type of the expression is no longer `void*`, so the compiler does not (and cannot) make the necessary adjustments.

Here is how to make the code in your example portable:

```
void* tmp = ptr; // (1)
wrapper_free(&tmp);
ptr = tmp;       // (2)
printf("%p\n", (void*)ptr);
```

This is portable, because `tmp` is `void*`, so `&tmp` is `void**`. The compiler gets an opportunity to do its "magic" on lines marked (1) and (2). Note that the compiler would need to do something to the same effect if it wanted to implement `void**` properly.